# Lowercase special characters with perl on 64-bit system

Tags: regex, perl

I want to process a text file which contains a long list of sentences which have the form :

```
<s>  Hello world  </s>
<s>  Ça world  </s>
<s>  He llo world  </s>
<s>  H.E.L.L.O world  </s>
```

I want to lowercase the first letter of the first word of each sentence ("Hello" -> "hello") using Perl (5.22.1). I also don't want to modify abbreviations (eg. A.B.C.). 
My problem is that the file might contain special characters (eg. Ç ) and I think their encoding gives Perl a hard time .

The file is encoded in ISO-8859-1. This is the code I use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);
use locale;
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_CA.ISO-8859-1");

while (<STDIN>) {

  s/(^<s> +)(\w[^\.\ ][^\ ]*)/
    $1.lc($2)
  /ge;

  print;
}
```

If I process the file with that code on cygwin (windows **64**-bit), the result I get is :

```
<s>  hello world  </s>
<s>  Ça world  </s>
<s>  he llo world  </s>
<s>  H.E.L.L.O world  </s>
```

The "Ç" character is still in uppercase.

If I process it on cygwin (windows **32**-bit), the result I get is :

```
<s>  hello world  </s>
<s>  ça world  </s>
<s>  he llo world  </s>
<s>  H.E.L.L.O world  </s>
```

The "Ç" character is now in lowercase.

I would like the code to work on both 32 and 64 bit windows - and to understand why it doesn't work as is.

Comment: What versions of 32- and 64-bit perl do you have?

Comment: 64-bit : v5.22.1, 32-bit : v5.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to specify the encoding of the input and output.

```
use open IO => ':encoding(iso-8859-1)', ':std';
```

You can also use

```
use open IO => ':locale', ':std';
```

but in that case, you need to set the locale in a BEGIN block before setting the `open` layer:

```
BEGIN { setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_CA.ISO-8859-1"); }
```